# android duplicate provider authority on apps that don't have provider

Tags: android

I have 7 apps on store, but when I try to install 3 of them I get duplicate provider authority error on the second of these 3 that I try to install.

none of my apps have provider in manifest...

any idea?

Comment: You might be getting a provider from some library that you are using. If you are using Android Studio, check the full manifest for your apps (including changes from libraries and Gradle) in `build/intermediates/manifests`.

Comment: i have checked all seems ok, two of these apps are very simple.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. I then checked the full manifest as suggested in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397365/android-duplicate-provider-authority-on-apps-that-dont-have-provider#comment54586099_33397365) above by Commonsware. My full manifest was having a provider but as it was merged from `play-service-measurement` library module, so at first glance it looked okay to me.

But actually it had the issue due to its authority. This provider has correctly declared its authorities attribute in its manifest with `${applicationId}` placeholder as a prefix. But due to a bug in build system, if app's `build.gradle` does not has any `applicationId` then this placeholder is being replaced by library's package name instead of our app's package name. It may result in multiple apps having same authority for this provider. Here is [a link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187317) for this issue.

As a workaround, we can just declare an applicationId in our `build.gradle`, which can be kept same as package name in manifest in most cases. In case you want to keep different values for these two, you can read further about the [differences between manifest's package name and build.gradle's `applicationId`](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename).

Answer (score 2):

This happens only on Lollipop 5.0.1 devices . It only happens if you have not declared `applicationId` on your `build.gradle`. This is due to play-service-measurement using `applicationId` parameter.

```
declare applicationId "com.your.package" on your gradle
```