# Google Play Services and "Duplicate Provider Authority"

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, google-play-services

I was using Google Play Services 7.8, I updated to the latest version, 8.4, and everything was fine on all my test devices. However, some users (a tiny minority) are reporting the error `Duplicate Provider Authority` when trying to install or update to the latest version.

With help from users I've narrowed this down to being caused by Google Play Services, but I can't figure out why it's happening or the exact cause.

My `.gradle` dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
    compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.10.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.amazon.android:mobile-ads:5.+'
}
```

Running `gradlew android:androidDependencies` produces the following output

```
+--- LOCAL: gameanalytics.jar
+--- LOCAL: in-app-purchasing-2.0.61.jar
+--- LOCAL: vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-3.3.3.jar
+--- LOCAL: dagger-1.2.2.jar
+--- LOCAL: nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar
+--- LOCAL: presage-lib-1.7.2-manual.jar
+--- LOCAL: javax.inject-1.jar
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    |    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
|    \--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1
+--- com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.10.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    |         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|                   \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|                        \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|                   \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
     |              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
          \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
               \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
                    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
                         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
```

Comment: possible duplicate - http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18953/what-is-the-duplicate-provider-error. The first referenced source suggests someone may have used the same provider authority you put.

Comment: @adjuremods As far as I can tell, this is purely related to Google Play Services 8.4. Changing nothing in my app except Google Play causes the problem. I don't specify any provider authority for the application.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this error occurs when the provider authority (Provider Name) has already been used. If the app's `build.gradle` file does not have an applicationId then the library package name is used as a default. If the app has not fully been removed from the device then this problem will be encountered.

I suggest the following:

- Change the applicationId in the build.gradle
- Advise your users to ensure that the app is fully removed by going to the Application Manager and if the app icon is seen and greyed out remove it

Please see the below answer for more information:

[android duplicate provider authority on apps that don't have provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33397365/android-duplicate-provider-authority-on-apps-that-dont-have-provider)

Hope this helps

Comment: This is occurring on devices that have never had the application installed before and it's definitely related to Google Play Services. With GPS 7.8 the app will always install quite happily.